# Best way to grab id from post to send along with comment to database

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs

So I have a social media page that has an array of posts stored in a sql database. Each post has an id, author, and body. I have another database for comments that will be associated with a certain post. My question is, what is the best way to send the id of the post that is being commented on, to the comment database so that each comment is linked to a post by its ID? When i later query the database i want to display comments on each post but not all the comments from the database, just the one that is associated with the post it was made on. Hope that all makes sense. Here is some of my code, I am open to any and all suggestions.
Post Component:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {AuthContext} from '../AuthContext';
import './Post.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Post = ({posts, getComment, comments, key}) => {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {username} = user;

  const [comment, setComment] = useState({
    author: username,
    comment: '',
    id: need this to be the id from the posts that are being passed in as props,
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/post/comment', comment);
       getComment()
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setComment({...comment, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    console.log(comment);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div className="postCard">
            <p className="author">{post.author}</p>
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <div className="postBody">
              <p>{post.body}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="comments">
              <form action="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                  type="textarea"
                  name="comment"
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <button>Comment</button>
              </form>
              <div>
                {' '}
                {comments.map((comment) => (
                  <div>
                    <p>{comment.author}</p>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>

              <p>
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have each post's id when you are mapping over them, so you can use it as an argument for handleSubmit like so:

```
<ul>
    {posts.map((post) => (
      <div className="postCard">
        <p className="author">{post.author}</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div className="postBody">
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="comments">
          // Send the event and the post's id
          <form action="submit" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, post.id)}>
            <input
              type="textarea"
              name="comment"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
            <button>Comment</button>
          </form>
          <div>
            {' '}
            {comments.map((comment) => (
              <div>
                <p>{comment.author}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

          <p>
            <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Then in your handleSubmit function you can send the post id along with the comment you are sending now to your backend.

```
// Receive the event and id
const handleSubmit = async (e, id) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    // Send comment and id to your backend
    const response = await axios.post('/post/comment', {comment, id});
     getComment()
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```